# I'm encountering an internal error while opening the android studio, what can i do?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I disabled the Kotlin plugin in android studio, and I'm encountering an internal error whenever I try to open the application. how can I resolve this issue

I want the solution of this problem

> ```
> error:com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore$EssentialPluginMissingException:
> ```
>
> Missing essential plugins: com.android.tools.design,
> org.jetbrains.android
> at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.checkEssentialPluginsAreAvailable(PluginManagerCore.java:750)
> at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:843)
> at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializeAndSetPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1047)
> at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginDescriptorLoader$scheduleLoading$pluginSetDeferred$1.invokeSuspend(PluginDescriptorLoader.kt:397)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)

Answer (score 1):

Title of problem : Missing essential plugins:+com.android.tools.design+org.jetbrains.android

(1) Navigate to C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3
Note: ensure to enable hidden items in your folder when you click on view.

inside your latest andorid studio version which is AndroidStudio2022.3 for me,
yours may be different.

(2)locate disable_plugin and delete it.
this solution is for (windows)